# Update Session every 2 minuts

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

i'm building  an MVC application that need to get updated data from the DB every 2 minutes,
i'm thinking about using Timer per session that will invoke SP every 2 minutes and will update the client with SignleR,
the thing i'm worry about is to hold Timer per session-this app will support 10,000 users
at the same time,
i'll be happy to get some advise 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Timer per process, not per session, and every time it fires and you get DB data process it to decide if you should do a SignalR broadcast/group/individual connections.

Answer (score 0):

How about building a single timer that persists for the lifecycle of the application:

```
public static class SessionTimer
{
    static _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    static List<Action> _delegates = new List<Action>();
    static Dictionary<string, Action> _delegateLookup = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    static object _lockObj = new Object();

    static SessionTimer()
    {
        _timer.Interval = 120000;
        _timer.Elapsed
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var d in _delegates)
        {
            d();
        }
    }

    public static Enlist(HttpSessionState s, Action d)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            _delegates.Add(d);
            _delegateLookup.Add(s.SessionID, d);
        }
    }

    public static Delist(HttpSessionState s)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            _delegates.Remove(_delegateLookup[s.SessionID]);
            _delegateLookup.Remove(s.SessionID);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is enlist the session when it starts. You could grab the `Session_Start` handler in `Global.asax` to do that:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SessionTimer.Enlist(HttpContext.Current.Session, someActionHandler);
}
```

or you could enlist whenever you wanted.

**DISCLAIMER:** the code I've provided is a guide and uncompiled. You'd need to modify the `SessionTimer` to be able to handle people enlisting more than once and much more. It's up to you to finish it.